# What is script working differently when called from Task Scheduler?

Tags: bash, windows-7, cygwin, windows-task-scheduler

I have this script that I have scheduled on WIndows 7 using:

```
SchTasks /Create /SC MINUTE  /TN CheckHS /TR "C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe C:\ShellStuff\checkHS.SH"
```

The script runs, but a BLANK line is written to checklog, when run from the scheduler. If I run the script from terminal the DATE gets added correctly. Why is it acting differently from the scheduler?

checkHS.SH:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x 

LOGDIR="/myd/Logs/"

CURDATE=`date '+%A %W %Y %X'`

echo $CURDATE >> $LOGDIR"checkLog"
```

Comment: Try after adding full path to `date` command, `CURDATE=$(/usr/bin/date '+%A %W %Y %X')` OR in Your case enter  the correct path to `date`

Comment: Also try `bash.exe -i` or `bash.exe -l`...

Comment: @Jord - full name did it - thanks

Comment: Adding it as an answer; else this would be an unanswered question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try after adding full path to `date` command,

`CURDATE=$(/usr/bin/date '+%A %W %Y %X')`

OR in Your case enter the **Correct path to `date`**