# Using commands in a bash script with 'which'

Tags: bash

Looking at bash scripts sometimes I see a construction like this:

```
MYSQL=`which mysql`
$MYSQL -uroot -ppass -e "SELECT * FROM whatever"
```

Where in other scripts the command (`mysql` in this case) is used directly:

```
mysql -uroot -ppass -e "SELECT * FROM whatever"
```

So, why and when should `which` be used and for which commands – I've never seen `echo` used with `which`…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just do `man which` for details:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> ```
>    which  returns the pathnames of the files (or links) which would be executed in the current environment,
>    had its arguments been given as commands in a strictly POSIX-conformant shell.  It does this by  search‐
>    ing  the  PATH  for  executable  files  matching the names of the arguments. It does not follow symbolic
>    links.
> ```

So `which mysql` just returns current path of the `mysql` command.

However use of `which` in your examples just **makes sure to ignore any alias set for `mysql` in your current environment**.

However there is another `clever shortcut` to avoid `which` in shell. You can use call mysql with backslash:

```
\mysql -uroot -ppass -e "SELECT * FROM whatever"
```

This will be **effectively same** as what your 2 commands are doing.

**From OP:** The only reason to use which is to avoid possible problems with custom aliases (like `alias mysql="mysql -upeter -ppaula"`). And since it is pretty unlikely somebody would set an alias for say `echo`, we don't need this construction with echo. But it is very common to set an alias for `mysql` (nobody wants to memorize and type the 24 chars long password).

Comment: I know that `which` returns the path of that command. My question is, why and when do I need it. `which echo` returns `/bin/echo` but nobody uses this construction with `echo`.

Comment: I just updated one use case of your example, (by storing `which` command's output it is ignoring any possible alias for mysql).

Comment: So, is there a recommended best practice which commands should be used with `which`? I wouldn't want to include a *anti alias file* with all the commands used in my bash script wrapped with `which`…

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but the answer to my question would be:
The only reason to use `which` is to avoid possible problems with custom aliases (like `alias mysql="mysql -upeter -ppaula"`). And since it is pretty unlikely somebody would set an alias for say `echo`, we don't need this construction with `echo`. But it is very common to set an alias for `mysql` (nobody wants to memorize and type the 24 chars long password)…

Comment: Yes that is nice way to put it, let me add it to answer for other readers.

Comment: Maybe you could also include this one good use case in favor of `which` in your answer: To put `MYSQL=\`which mysql\`` at the beginning of the script (or in an extra .config-file) enables the user to call a different than default installation of `mysql` replacing `which mysql` with for example `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/mysql`.

Answer (score 1):

Largely they both are same:

Just `which` **returns the absolute path of the binary**. Sometimes special conditions when you are working with some third program executing the script or preparing the environment in which this script would run  the entire path of the binary comes in handy.

Like in case of a scheduler. If you have scheduled one script then you will like to use the binary with its absolute path.

Hence:

```
mysql=`which mysql`
```

or

```
mysql=$(which mysql)
```

or even

```
/usr/bin/mysql <flags>
```

Your script from scheduler might have run using

```
mysql ....<flags>
```

but it wasn't a guarantee as explained in the previous post. Alias may be one of the reasons.

**[For the kind of problems *not using the absolute path* can bring, check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682186/what-is-script-working-differently-when-called-from-task-scheduler/23689283#23689283)**

Comment: Yes, I was remotely thinking of this as well. If the script is being called for example by `php` the absolute path is often required: `exec('/usr/local/bin/mysql -uroot -ppass -e "SELECT * FROM whatever"');`  
(of course you wouldn't call `mysql` with `exec` in php…)